# make a javascript variable equal to php variable

Tags: javascript, php

I know how to make a php variable equal to javascript variable like this :

```
<?php 
//somewhere set a value 
$var = "a value";?> 
<script>
// then echo it into the js/html stream
// and assign to a js variable
spge = '<?php echo $var ;?>';
// then
alert(spge);
</script>
```

But i need to do the opposite. I Tried :

```
$var = echo "<script type = 'text/javascript'> var spge </script>";
```

But it didn't work.

Can someone help me? Am I totally wrong?

Thank you

Comment: `$var = echo "<script type = 'text/javascript'> var spge </script>";` ?? You can't use `echo` inside a `variable` declaration like that. You need to use `AJAX`. PHP is a serverside language and JavaScript is client side. Asynchronous JavaScript will help you with that. You can read about *`AJAX`* **[here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)**.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between 'server-side' and 'client-side' code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually , you cant "send/pass/assign" javascript variable to php.
When you request a web page, the server sends the documents. The server cannot receive anything "automatically" from the client. You must use a specific technology to achive this. This technology could be websockets, ajax or a simple html form with action and method. So in case for a single variable can be ajax, choose a condition and send ajax request if you dont want to reload you page, or html form submit if you don't care about the reloading of web page. You can pass/send the variable and retrive it from the php with the GET or POST method.

see these examples https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp